# How to keep track of processed git commits?

Tags: git, tags, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

We are getting resources for a project through a git repo and need to keep track of which resources are already used and which ones still need processing.

I tried working with a tag "already-processed" and moving the tag to the newest commit, but somehow SourceTree is not able to update the repos on fetch/pull and it is causing a lot of problems.

So the question is, if there is maybe a nicer intended way to handle all that or if not, how to make it work correctly with the tags?

We are processing the resources chronologically, but would also be nice to mark individual commits as processed/todo one day.

Environment is Gitlab + SourceTree, but command line solutions would work too, just to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update `tags` you need to pass flag `--tags` with `git fetch`.

```
$ git fetch --tags    # update the tags (all necessary commits for tag)
$ git tag             # see the available tags

$ git fetch           # update the commits/changes
```

**Note:** If you want to be up to date, must run both commands

Comment: Okay, Sourcetree has a flag "Fetch and store all tags locally" when fetching, so I have to call the dialog twice, first time with the checkbox on and second time without. Annoying, but at least working. Will wait if somebody comes up with a different approach to it, but this basically would be the accepted answer otherwise. Thanks!